# Three elements in one node of a linked list

Tags: c++, linked-list, nodes, element

I am trying to understand linked lists and am having a difficult time. I want to put three elements in a node and then print multiple nodes out. However, I am only able to print the first element of a node. 
For example: 
Input: 1, 2, 3 
Output: 1 NULL

```
struct node
{
    int Intx, Inty, Intz;
    struct node *p;
}

class linked
{
public:
    node* create_node(int first, int second, int third);
    int Intx, Inty, Intz;
    void insert();
    void display();
}

main()
{
    linked sl;
    sl.insert();
    sl.display();
}

node *linked::create_node(int first, int second, int third)
{
    Intx = first;
    Inty = second;
    Intz = third;
    struct node *temp, *p;
    temp = new (struct node);
    if (temp == NULL)
    {
        cout << "Not able to complete";
    }
    else
    {
        temp->Intx = first, Inty = second, Intz = third;
        temp->next = NULL;
        return temp;
    }
}

void linked::insert()
{
    int Intx, Inty, Intz;
    cout << "Enter First Element for node: ";
    cin >> Intx;
    cout << "Enter Second Element for node: ";
    cin >> Inty;
    cout << "Enter Third Element for node: ";
    cin >> Intz;
    struct node *temp, *s;
    temp = create_node(Intx, Inty, Intz);
    if (start == NULL)
    {
        start = temp;
        start->next = NULL;
    }
    else
    {
        s = start;
        start = temp;
        start->next = s;
    }
    cout << "Element Inserted." << endl;
}

void linked::display()
{
    struct node *temp;
    cout << "Elements of list are: " << endl;
    while (temp != NULL)
    {
        cout << temp->Intx, Inty, Intz;
        temp = temp->next;
    }
    cout << "NULL" << endl;
}
```

Comment: Need semicolons ';' after the struct and class definitions. main must return int. Functions with a non-void return type (create_node for example) must return a value for all paths in the function. Comma operator abuse has already been covered in an answer. Injblue, you need to dive back into the textbook and work on some basic program building before you can be helped effectively. Beware of taking answers you can simply cut and paste as this will lead to you learning to be a [Cargo Cult Programmer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cargo_cult_programming).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
temp-> Intx = first, Inty = second, Intz = third;
```

separating things with commas doesn't do what you think it does here.  You should use three statements and you have to include `temp->` in each:

```
temp->Intx = first;
temp->Inty = second;
temp->Intz = third;
```

If you really want to use the comma operator, you can, but you will still need `temp->` on all three assignments.

Similarly, the commas you're using in `display` don't do what you want

```
cout<< temp->Intx, Inty, Intz;
```

should be

```
cout<< temp->Intx << "," << temp->Inty << "," << temp->Intz;
```

Or something like that depending on how you want it formatted

Answer (score 0):

Rather than discussing what's wrong in your code. I would rather suggest you understand the logic behind linked list Algorithm. This would help you grow.

The links [Link1: Youtube tut](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=U-MfAoL6qjM) and [Link 2](http://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/lesson15.html) will provide you basic of how link-list algorithm works.

1. Since the program is made using C++. The Link 1 is a youtube tutorial providing step by step on each linked list operation in visual studio using C++ programming. This might help you understand proper use of `->` operator. Plus, it may also help you understand relation between object and its members.
2. While Link 2 only helps with theoretical aspects of how link list as a data structure grows and how it could be maintained.

Comment: While I agree with the assessment and the intent, you should summarize the links to make this a real answer. At the moment this is a comment, not an answer

Comment: @user4581301 I am sorry I would have provided it as comment but don't have enough reputation to give a comment. I tried to fix my answere. But If you suggest I would be happy to flag my answere to  keep stack clean.